# microsoft.win32.savefiledialog issue in windows xp

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, windows-xp

I am using microsoft.win32.savefiledialog  to save a file inside a folder. **Only in windows XP**, after saving file in a folder (ex: abc) , I cannot delete abc folder. Error message displays saying that another process is using this. Seems like handles are remaining on selected folder. Please give me a solution on this.

Following is my save file dialog code:

```
SaveFileDialog fileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

fileDialog.DefaultExt = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DefaultExtension) ? this.DefaultExtension : "*.*";
fileDialog.Filter = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter) ? Filter : "All Files|*.*";
fileDialog.FileName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileName) ? this.FileName : string.Empty;
fileDialog.InitialDirectory = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DefaultPath) ? this.DefaultPath : string.Empty;

if (fileDialog.ShowDialog().Value == true)
{
    fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
}
else
{
    fileName = string.Empty;
}            

return fileName;
```

**EDITED :**

This is common for System.Windows.Forms also, I tried lot, issue happnes when I select a folder from file dialog window. no need to do anything after that, just select a folder form save file dialog. that foldercannot be deleted .

Comment: Note that you don't show code to save file... Please confirm that the problem is not related to save code itself (i.e. even if you don't save file but just get file name you still see folder locked).

Comment: @Sayse when I am trying to add using it gives error saying microsoft.win32.savefiledialog should be implement IDisposable interface .

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It happens only if I save the file in selected folder

Comment: ah sorry, get it confused with OpenFileDialog.. you should include the code where it actually errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely normal.  It is not another process that has the directory object opened, it is *your* process.  Your code made the directory the default working directory of your process.  Something you can see from the Environment.CurrentDirectory property.

Set the `SaveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory` property to true to avoid this.